# ARC works for all objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

In [Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143023024X) I found a sentence that tells me that ARC releases only Object from Foundation. Is this true? So if i have:

```
MySimpleClass *objectFromMySimpleClass = [MySimpleClass alloc] init];
```

I should release objectFromMySimpleClass? How can i do that? When i'm try

```
[objectFromMySimpleClass release];
```

I see unactive "release" in Xcode hints and then compiler say that i cannot do this, becouse of ARC. So what's going on?

And other thing. When i use NSCoping protocol i should also release object when i use **copy** ?

Comment: Doesn't it mean the `NSObject` class?  If so your class is derived from that class, so all is well.

Comment: I'm just follow the book author ;) So when i inherit from NSObject this is totally cool. This make sense, i didn't think of that. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're linking to the right book? That one was written before ARC was unveiled, so I doubt it has any mention of ARC within it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MySimpleClass` inherits `NSObject`, hence it is a Foundation Object, so it can be managed by ARC.

Comment: Except in the case that the class overrides retain/release. In classes like that (such as NSWindow at the time of writing), I believe you must use a non-zeroing weak variable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,ARC Work for all object and you cant use release and retain at runtime.